# Android: retrieve website html - not working

Tags: java, android

I have scoured the internet, and developed code that I thought would work to get the `html` of a website in readable form. However, I am still unable to make this work. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://www.cnn.com");

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpGet httpGet = null;
            HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
            String s = "";

            try {
                if(mHttpClient == null){
                    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                }


                httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);


                response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
                s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            final TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headline);
            textview1.setText(result);

        }
    }
}
```

When I try this, the app crashes on startup, with the `LogCat` shown below:

```
07-26 16:13:42.561: W/dalvikvm(23584): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416dfda0)
07-26 16:13:42.561: E/AndroidRuntime(23584): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-26 16:13:42.561: E/AndroidRuntime(23584): Process: com.app.firstapp, PID: 23584
07-26 16:13:42.561: E/AndroidRuntime(23584): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

I have no idea why this is happening, does anyone know how I can modify my code to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace.  And tell us what line of doInBackground it names in the crash

Comment: @GabeSechan is the stack trace the same as LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

A library that might be helpful to you is jsoup. 
Link: http://jsoup.org

To get a pages HTML in jsoup you just do:

Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

And then from this HTML you can use Jsoup to parse whatever data from the HTML you need.
Link: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

Edit: I miss read the question. I thought you were having trouble with getting the HTML instead of the fact that there was a problem in the backgrounding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in your Manifest file.